# How could I use arrays in this?

Tags: java, arrays

For my assignment, I am supposed to, "Write the code for your parent class(es) and the child classes and write a driver class to demonstrate the methods and variables of your application. In your driver, include an array to store objects of all your child classes. Use a loop to print out the relevant values of each object and/or use its methods."

Well, this is what I have made so far:

Dog (Abstract Class):

```
    package objectsofaffection;

    public abstract class Dog extends Test {

        static String name;
        static String age;
        static String coatColor;

        public abstract void name();
        public abstract void age();
        public abstract void coatColor();
}
```

DogBetty:

```
package objectsofaffection;

public class DogBetty extends Dog {

    public DogBetty() {
        name();
        age();
        coatColor();
    }


    @Override
    public void name() {
        System.out.println("Dog Name: Betty");
        }
    @Override
    public void age() {
        System.out.println("Age: 11 years");
        }
    @Override
    public void coatColor() {
        System.out.println("Coat Color: Brown");

        }
    }
```

DogCarl:

```
package objectsofaffection;

public class DogCarl extends Dog {

    public DogCarl() {
        name();
        age();
        coatColor();
    }


    @Override
    public void name() {
        System.out.println("Dog Name: Carl");
        }

    public void age() {
        System.out.println("Age: 2 months");
        }

    public void coatColor() {
        System.out.println("Coat Color: Black");

        }
    }
```

DogJoe:

```
package objectsofaffection;

public class DogJoe extends Dog {

    public DogJoe() {
        name();
        age();
        coatColor();
    }


    @Override
    public void name() {
        System.out.println("Dog Name: Joe");
        }

    public void age() {
        System.out.println("Age: 6 years");
        }

    public void coatColor() {
        System.out.println("Coat Color: Spotted Black and White");

        }
    }
```

DogMollie:

```
package objectsofaffection;

public class DogMollie extends Dog {

    public DogMollie() {
        name();
        age();
        coatColor();
    }


    @Override
    public void name() {
        System.out.println("Dog Name: Mollie");
        }

    public void age() {
        System.out.println("Age: 3 years");
        }

    public void coatColor() {
        System.out.println("Coat Color: Black, Brown, White mix.");

        }
    }
```

Test (Driver Class):

```
package objectsofaffection;

public class Test {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DogBetty betty = new DogBetty();
            System.out.println(); //space

        DogJoe joe = new DogJoe();
            System.out.println(); //space

        DogCarl carl = new DogCarl();
            System.out.println(); //space

        DogMollie mollie = new DogMollie();
            System.out.println(); //space

    } 
}
```

So, how could I possibly use arrays? Help please.

Comment: You could use an array of type `Dog`. That would allow you to store a reference to an object of any class that extends `Dog`.

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't need a `SuppressWarnings("unused")` annotation on a `main` method.

Comment: Why are u extending `Test` in `Dog` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't have make child class for each dog, an abstract class represents a type, and child class represents a sub-type. so in your if `Dog` is parent class, your child class can be breeds and for each dog you make an object.

`Dog`-> `germanShepard extends Dog` ->  `germanShepard dogMollie = new germanShepard();`

Then you can use ArrayList of type germanShepard: `ArrayList<germanShepard> dogs = new ArrayList<germanShepard>();`

`dogs.add(dogMollie);` ArrayList is dynamic data structure so it grows according to your need

but if you want to use array,

`germanShepard[] dogs;`

`dogs =new germanShepard[10];`

`dogs[0] = new germanShepard(name,age,coatColor);`

Comment: As a side note, class names should always begin with a capital letter in Java. See [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: yeah, i am using java after a long time. need re-familiarize myself with the naming conventions.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted answer from Salman, I must point out that your parent class declared 3 static variables.  Static variables are shared across all instances of the class, so when those are set, every instance of dog will have the same name, age, color.  Fortunately, those variables are never set, so they just illustrate you're confused about their purpose and the use of 'static'.   Also, note that everyone of your child classes do the same thing.  This is a hint you should move that logic into the parent class.   Each child class constructor should call super(),  and the super class constructor would call those same 3 methods.